# How to Migrate From freescale Kinetis L series MCUs to Kinetis K series

Tags: arm, codewarrior, cortex-m

I want to implement Modbus on my TWR-K20D72M . For that I found in the Modbus Suite Provided by http://www.embedded-solutions.at/index.php/en/products/modbus-slave  (Link) .
I can see the have the Demo for Modbus slave for Freescale Cortex M0 KL25Z (ASCII and RTU) .

So My question is what changes Will I have to make in order to migrate from MKL25Z128LK4 to TWR-K20D72M board .

Comment: You're talking about Modbus slave, yet you provide a link to a Modbus master library. Which one are you really trying to use ?

Comment: @Alexandre   Now I edited the link in the question..... Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Since Modbus is a library used by the MCU and the peripherals between Kinetis K and Kinetis L families are almost the same, you shouldn't have any problem migrating between them.

Answer (score 0):

KL and KK has different pinmaps, both MKL25Z128LK4 and TWR-K20D72M have occupied peripherals that you may not allow to use. so I think you have to remap your pins, and resign modules. If you are using Process Expert, you may need to check if the components you are using are available for both chip sets.